# Почему не отображается содержимое h:outputLabel?

Tags: java, spring, jsf

Здравствуйте. Изучаю интеграцию JSF & Spring. Есть xhtml страница:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:body>
       <h1>Welcome to PlantPlaces.com</h1>
       <h:outputLabel value="#{applicationInfo.slogan}" />
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

Если вне элемента h:outputLabel, то отображается значение slogan:

```
#{applicationInfo.slogan}
```

Вот Bean:

```
package com.plantplaces.ui;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope("session")
public class ApplicationInfo {

    String slogan = "Promoting Plant Diversity through Education.";

    public String getSlogan() {
        return slogan;
    }

    public void setSlogan(String slogan) {
        this.slogan = slogan;
    }

}
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь h:outputText вместо h:outputLabel. Если не изменяет память, outputLabel используется для привязки к компоненту формы.

Comment: h:outputText тоже не отображается

Comment: А если в h:outputText внести просто константу то что-то отобразится?
<h:outputText value="test"/>
И jsf какой версии используете? Похоже у вас jsf < 2.2 Можете попробовать такой namespace xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"

Comment: Никак не отображается. Ни константа, ни с предложенным вами пространством имен

Comment: Где запускаете? Про namespace к чему спрашивал: у Вас 

xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" и   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"

Они к разным версиям относятся.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки. Разобрался.

Comment: welcome. Но все же прочтите про outputLabel. Например тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544141/purpose-of-the-houtputlabel-and-its-for-attribute

Answer (score 1):

Изменил заголовок страницы(добавил xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core")
теперь все отображается:

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:body>
       <h1>Welcome to PlantPlaces.com!</h1>
       <em><h:outputLabel value="#{applicationInfo.slogan}" /></em>
    </h:body>

    </html>
```